# Given multiple ranges, if multiple conditions are met then hide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide rows under this condition:

```
#given some ranges within column B and C 
#for each row within the ranges 
#if the related cells in column B and C both have value equal to 0 
#then hide the specific row
```

This is the code I'm using, but I'm struggling to implement the if part where both cells have to have value = to 0

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim r0 As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, MultiRange As Range, r As Range

Set r0 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:C6")
Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:C8")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10:C11")
Set MultiRange = Union(r0, r1, r2)

For Each r In MultiRange
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = (r.Value = 0)
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. In fact you already solved the harder part (unioning ranges). Set your loop to move through the `rows` in the unioned range instead of the default `cells`

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim r0 As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, MultiRange As Range, r As Range

Set r0 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:C6")
Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:C8")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10:C11")
Set MultiRange = Union(r0, r1, r2)

For Each r In MultiRange.Rows
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = (r.Cells(1,1).value = 0 AND r.cells(1, 2).value = 0)
Next r

End Sub
```